# React Mui DataGrid - insert line break when text inside row hits max width

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, datagrid, line-breaks

I have a table that I created using MUI DataGrid, and I am storing some user input.
My issue is, if the text input is too big, the text will truncate showing "..." at the end.
What I'm trying to achieve is to break the line inside that column if the text is too big, here is the example.
[image]

I want the text to be broken into more lines if it hits the end of the column.

Here is my code:

```
const columnData: GridColDef[] = [
    {
      field: "createdAt",
      headerName: "DATE",
      minWidth: 150,
      width: 244,
      valueFormatter: (params: GridValueFormatterParams) =>
        dateString(DateTime.fromSeconds(params.value as number).toJSDate()),
    },
    {
      field: "content",
      headerName: "NOTE",
      minWidth: 600,
      width: 1150,
    },
    {
      field: "note-menu-button",
      disableColumnMenu: true,
      sortable: false,
      headerName: "",
      width: 0,
      renderCell: (params) => {
        return (
          <ActionMenu
            id="note-menu-button"
            menuItems={menu}
            rowId={params.id}
          />
        );
      },
    },
  ];
return (
    <Table
      {...props}
      columns={columnData}
      rowHeight={55}
      autoHeight
      pageSize={6}
    />
  );
};
```

Here is where I load the table:

```
<Card id="notes-table" sx={{ mb: 4 }}>
        <CardContent>
          <NotesTable
            onNotesEditClick={(id: string) => {
              openEditNoteDialog(id);
            }}
            onNotesDeleteClick={(id: string) => {
              onDeleteNote(id);
            }}
            rows={notes}
            loading={loading}
          />
        </CardContent>
      </Card>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Please try below code.**

*Add rendercell as shown below.*

```
renderCell: (cellValues) => {
  return (
    <TextField
      value={cellValues.row.value}
      InputProps={{ disableUnderline: true }}
      multiline
    />
  )
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

use render cell method in note column and write function component and write your logic if more than some length go next line then just pass your data to that function component

Answer (score 0):

Using this valueGetter you can adjust the length of the row , value length.

```
{
      field: "description",
      headerName: "Description",
      minWidth: 300,
      sortable: false,
      flex: 1,
      valueGetter: (params) => params.value ? 
                   params.value.toString().slice(0, 34) + 
                   (params.value.toString().length > 34 ? "..." : " ")
                   : params.value,
      headerClassName: "super-app-theme--header",
}
```